# Create an text file with numpy array of facial lanmark detection.?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, dlib

I am trying to make an face swap application for which I have facial landmark detection code. But,since I am new to programming world, I have made my code longer than needed. I know, there is some short way to do it, I just do not know how. So. here is my code:

```
predictor_path = "C:\\Users\\G7K4\\Desktop\\FinalFaceSwap\\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
filepath1 =  "C:\\Users\\G7K4\\Desktop\\FinalFaceSwap\\Image\\nil.jpg"

image1 = cv2.imread(filepath1)


detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path) 
dets1 = detector(image1)

for k, d in enumerate(dets1):
shape = predictor(img1, d)
#Detect 68 facial landmark points
vec = np.empty([68, 2], dtype = int)
for b in range(68):
    vec[b][0] = shape.part(b).x
    vec[b][1] = shape.part(b).y

#write the detected file in text file
with open("Model1.txt","w") as file:
    for i in range(len(vec)):
        outer=""
        outer += str(vec[i])
        file.write(outer)
        file.write("\n")

#read the text file and remove the brackets
with open("Model1.txt","r") as my_file:
    text=my_file.read()
    text= text.replace("[","")
    text= text.replace("]","")

#again write the file. 
with open("Model1.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(text)

#function for reading points from text file
def readPoints(path) :
    # Create an array of points.
    points = [];

    # Read points
    with open(path) as file :
        for line in file :
            x, y = line.split()
            points.append((int(x), int(y)))
    return points
```

So, here, i need to detect facial landmarks and read it directly so it can be used for face swap. Or, if it cannot be done, i need to detect facial landmarks and write it into text file without bracket at once, so that, i do not have to read and write the text file twice and remove brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package called `imutils` for working with dlib facial landmark. Run `pip install imutils` to install it. Here is the short way to do it

```
from imutils import face_utils

shape = predictor(img1, d)
shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

# access the x-coordinate point 20 
x_20 = shape[20][0]

# access the y-coordinate point 54 
y_54 = shape[54][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to write the numpy matrix data in text format and remove the parenthesis later. Instead `numpy` already provides [`np.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`np.load()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) methods for serialization and deserialization purposes.

I will provide you with a sample here, Also it is a good practise to encapsulate your read and write functions in separate methods so that when you change the reading/writing logic, you do not need to scan the whole code.

Create random facial feature points:

```
facial_points = np.zeros((68, 2), dtype=np.uint8)

# Fill in some absurd values:
for i in xrange(68):
    facial_points[i] = np.asarray([i, i%10])
```

Utility methods for reading and writing data:

```
def serialize_feature_points(feature_points, file_path):
    np.save(file_path, feature_points)


def deserialize_feature_points(file_path):
    return np.load(file_path)
```

Time for some action:

```
serialize_feature_points(facial_points, "feature_points1.npy")
print deserialize_feature_points("feature_points1.npy")

[[ 0  0]
 [ 1  1]
 [ 2  2]
 .... 
 [65  5]
 [66  6]
 [67  7]]
```